# Ruby/Bundler - How to force a ruby executable embedded in a gem to use the Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have created a gem 'mygem' that contains an executable (bin/mygem). The gemspec file defines some dependencies like :

```
gem.add_dependency('othergem', '< 1.0')
```

On my computer I have 2 versions of othergem : 0.9 and 1.0.

- When I run **bundle exec bin/mygem**, the 0.9 version of othergem is correctly loaded.
- When I run **bin/mygem**, that's the last version of othergem (1.0) which is loaded.

Logical. The problem is when I install the gem 'mygem' on a computer that has already the 1.0 version of othergem. RubyGems will install the 0.9 version of othergem in order to satisfy the gem dependencies. But when running in a terminal **mygem** (the binstub generated by RubyGems), that's the 1.0 version which is loaded.

**Question** : How to make my executable load the 0.9 version without embedding the gem othergem in a vendor-like folder ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec mygem`?  That should run the bundled version (0.9).  I think you are executing the direct path to the file installed on your computer which will always be 1.0.

Comment: bundle exec when given a path to an executable will just run it in the context of bundler, but not the bundled one.

Comment: This works okay for me when I test it. Are you sure you’re running the wrapper generated by rubygems and not directly running the file in the gems bin directory? What does `which mygem` give you? That’s the only thing I can think of that would cause what you’re seeing.

Comment: while bundler should make this happen, you could also use rvms gemsets feature.

Comment: @matt : yes that's the wrapper generated by rubygems (/home/aymeric/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/mygen). Could you give me an example that works for you ?

Comment: @Aymeric have a look at https://gist.github.com/mattwildig/5013595. I’ve used Haml as my `othergem`. The versions are `< 4.0`, so maybe having a version with a leading `0` causes a difference. Also I’m installing direct from the `.gem` file rather than via Rubygems. I don’t think either of these things should cause a problem though.

Comment: @matt. You're right, it worked. I resolved my problem by being more accurate on my gem dependencies. It seems that, contrary to bundler, the rubygems dependency resolve read each requirement independently. So instead of defining only one strict inclusion, I added one and it worked.